# Memory debugger for mixed-mode C++ applications

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, mixed-mode

I have to maintain a large C++ mixed-mode application (VC++ 2005, CLR-support: /clr:oldsyntax). I suspect the program has a number of memory leaks but it's hard to find them manually. For native C++ applications we use Purify (and Valgrind on Linux).

Unfortunately Purify does not support mixed mode assemblies. Anybody here knows a decent memory debugger with support for mixed mode assemblies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/).  I've used it and it's pretty decent.  They also provide a free trial version that's unhindered (last I checked).